# Spring List of interface type data binding - how?

Tags: forms, spring, data-binding, binding, spring-mvc

Tried to find the answer on the Web but failed. Should be simple for pro Spring Devs... so here it comes:

In few words I want to bind the List of interface type: List to the form and get the data back (possibly modified by user via form. The problem is that it doesn't work :(

my code (short version) - command/model class which is passed to the form:

```
public class RoomsFormSearchResultCommand extends RoomsFormSearchCommand {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List<IRoom> roomsList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<Room>(),
            FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Room.class));

    public List<IRoom> getRoomsList() {
        return roomsList;
    }

    public void setRoomsList(final List<IRoom> roomsList) {
        this.roomsList = roomsList;
    }

(...)
```

then in the form I use it like that (short version):

```
    <form:form method="post" action="reserve" commandName="roomsResultsCmd">
(...)
    <c:forEach var="room" items="${roomsResultsCmd.roomsList}"
                varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td><form:input path="roomsList[${status.index}].roomNumber" readonly="true"/>
(...)
```

The form is displayed fine but after submitting it I get:

```
2012-01-22 21:31:55 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [wyspa] in context with path [/wyspa] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'roomsList[0]' of bean class [com.wyspa.controller.command.RoomsFormSearchResultCommand]: Illegal attempt to get property 'roomsList' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'roomsList' of bean class [com.wyspa.controller.command.RoomsFormSearchResultCommand]: Could not instantiate property type [com.wyspa.entity.IRoom] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.wyspa.entity.IRoom] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'roomsList' of bean class [com.wyspa.controller.command.RoomsFormSearchResultCommand]: Could not instantiate property type [com.wyspa.entity.IRoom] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.wyspa.entity.IRoom
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.newValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:633)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.growCollectionIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:863)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:555)
```

(...)

**The deal is then when I change the List to "instances" list everything works fine!**

```
public class RoomsFormSearchResultCommand extends RoomsFormSearchCommand {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//notice that the List is now List<Room>
    private List<Room> roomsList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<Room>(),
            FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Room.class));
```

In this case data is passed to the controller in proper way.

Since I am used to devlop on interfaces and I am pretty crazy about it I would REALLY prefer not to translate the `List<IRoom>` (which comes back from services) to `List<Room>` which seems to suit Spring. Is it possible to work with `List<IRoom>` in this case or Spring just doesn't support it?

//Of course Room implements IRoom - but I guess you already got that...

I would be VERY happy for any help/suggestions!

Best Regards,
Nirwan

Answer (score 3):

I have exact the same problem. Changing to following won't fix the problem. It looks spring binding ignores the factory utils and tries to instantiate the null object itself:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<IRoom> roomsList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<IRoom>(),
    FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Room.class));
```

The workaround is to set auto grow nested path off in your controller:

```
@InitBinder protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
    super.initBinder(request, binder);
 }
```

The problem is you'll lose the handy nested path like user.account.address.street. You have to make sure none of user, account, addresss is null. It does cause a lot of problems. That's why I came here, see if I can find better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need the list to auto-grow, you can store the form object in the session to avoid the nasty side effects of disabling auto-growing nested paths.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(types = RoomsFormSearchResultCommand.class)
public final class SearchController {

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(final Model model) {
            RoomsFormSearchResultCommand form = ... // create or load form
            model.addAttribute(form); 
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmitUpdateCart(
                    @ModelAttribute final RoomsFormSearchResultCommand form,
                    final BindingResult result,
                    final SessionStatus status) {
            // if result has no errors, just set status to complete
            status.setComplete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following lines

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<IRoom> roomsList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<IRoom>(),
    FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Room.class));
```

don't have time to try that myself, but it would make sense.